# Lighttpd set rewrite mod to hide php extension

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, lighttpd

I'm running my web host using `lighttpd`.

And now I would like to hide php extension from:
Example:

```
http://localhost/mis/display.php
```

to be:

```
http://localhost/mis/display
```

What I've done:

Active the mod_rewrite on `/etc/lighttpd/lighttpd.conf`

And I have `.htaccess` file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule (.*) $1\.php [L]

ErrorDocument 404 /mis/404
```

But still got `404 - Not Found`

Comment: lighttpd does not support .htaccess files and the commands in the .htaccess file you posted are commands for the Apache web server.